# Duplicate like, different end python

Tags: pandas, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have asked this question before, without getting a proper ansswer, trying now differently.

For example:
If I got a column named `A45-443-FGH-02A` and another column named `A45-443-FGH-02B`. They are "duplicate like" but with a different letter on the end.
I need to choose only these with the B in the end, and if the column name has "A" on the end it must be deleted.
I thought to choose by length but I didn't success.

Comment: can you create a working example with a data to test on and an expected output to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove duplicated columns names ending by `A`, if not duplicated then not:

```
c = ['A45-443-FGH-02A','A45-443-FGH-02B','B45-02A']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=c)
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A45-443-FGH-02A, A45-443-FGH-02B, B45-02A]

m1 = df.columns.str[:-1].duplicated(keep=False)
m2 = df.columns.str.endswith('A')

df = df.loc[:, (m1 & ~m2) | ~m1]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A45-443-FGH-02B, B45-02A]
Index: []
```

If working with column like `A`:

```
c = ['A45-443-FGH-02A','A45-443-FGH-02B','B45-02A']

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':c})
print (df)
                 A
0  A45-443-FGH-02A
1  A45-443-FGH-02B
2          B45-02A

m1 = df.A.str[:-1].duplicated(keep=False)
m2 = df.A.str.endswith('A')

df = df[(m1 & ~m2) | ~m1]
print (df)
                 A
1  A45-443-FGH-02B
2          B45-02A
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a check between A and B and you need attributes with B only.

```
df.loc[df['yourColumnName'].apply(lambda x: x.endswith('B'))]
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work one by one but if I need to find all "duplicate like" in the table?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A45-443-FGH-02B","A45-443-FGH-02A","ABC","CDE"])

s = df.columns.sort_values()

print (df[[i[-1] for i in s.groupby(s.str[:-1]).values()]])

#
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A45-443-FGH-02B, ABC, CDE]
Index: []
```

Comment: I think problem is not specify ending by `A`, so if different data it fail like `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A45-443-FGH-02B","A45-443-FGH-02C","ABC","CDE"])`

Comment: I tried to make a general solution to keep the last lookalike columns - but yes, it might or might not be suitable. Better if he provides sample data and output.

Comment: ya, OP need remove by `A` and `B` ending data, your solution working different, so added comment